# Generate SQL Server Backups on Remote Network Share

Tags: sql-server, impersonation, database-backups, execute

I am trying to build a stored procedure to backup a database(s) and take that backup to a remote storage location. Problem is the remote location isn't joined to the domain and no permissions I try to set will allow the SQL Server Service user to write to the location in question.

The go to solution to this that I've seen in my research is to change the service user to a user with permissions (in this case Administrator) but for reasons I cannot do this.

My best guess at the moment is to use an `EXECUTE AS` statement to impersonate a different Windows user but nothing I am doing seems to work. I haven't worked with the EXECUTE statement or user impersonation in SQL so I'm not certain if this is even something you can do.

Any help or guidance is very appreciated!